# How can I quickly change the color of text in a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, text-formatting, autohotkey

How can I quickly, with either a single or double click, assign a color to the text in a cell in Google Sheets?

In order to quickly determine the status of certain pieces of data in a spreadsheet I manage, I assign a text color to a cell's value. I do this dozens of times several times each month, and it is very tedious as it is dependent on an external, manual process (e.g. look at the value in a cell, go do the manual process, come back and manually update the color of the cell's text).

I've looked at running a script or macro when I double-click each cell (not currently available), adding a drop-down to the cell along with the existing value of the cell (not possible as far as I can tell), adding a checkbox to the cell along with the existing cell value (doesn't seem to be possible), and using text formatting from the right-click menu (not available).

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that it's possible to **assign a keyboard shortcut** to Google Sheets macros?<sup>(rethorical question)</sup>

From [Automate tasks in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7665004?hl=en) (emphasis mine)

> ## Edit your macro
>
> You can change the name, **add a keyboard shortcut**, edit the script, or remove a macro.
>
> 1. On your computer, open a spreadsheet at sheets.google.com.
> 2. At the top, click Tools and then Macros and then Manage macros.
> 3. Make your changes. To remove a macro or edit the script, next to a macro, click More More.
> 4. Click Update.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a desktop script by creating a macro for color change:

- first you will need to click on the toolbar/ribbon to escape the cell

  [image: 0]
- now use this combo:

  ---

  ## [image] 10x + [image] 15x + [image] 3x + select color
- now you can use something like **[AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/)** to save this combo (including that initial click) under one key. for example:

  - red color under **F7** key: 

    ```
    click + tab (10x) + right arrow (15x) + down arrow (4x) + right arrow (1x) + enter
    ```
  - reset (black) color under **F8** key: 

    ```
    click + tab (10x) + right arrow (15x) + down arrow (1x) + enter
    ```